# Nifi Encrypt json

Tags: json, encryption, apache-nifi

I would like to use nifi to encrypt the attributes in a json but not the keys as I would like to upload the data to a mongodb server. Is there a way to do this? For the project I an using twitter data as a proof of concept. So far I have used the EvaluateJsonPath processor to extract only the text of the tweet, and I can encrypt this text, however the resulting json no longer has a key. Can Nifi recreate a json that attaches a key to this attribute that I extracted? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this workflow isn't well supported by existing Apache NiFi processors. You could probably fashion a workflow that split the JSON content into attributes, split each attribute into the content of an individual flowfile, encrypted that content, merged the flowfiles back, and reconstituted the now-encrypted content into a attributes via `UpdateAttribute`.

I have [created a Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2961) for a new NiFi processor to make this much simpler. My recommendation until such time as that is available is to use the `ExecuteScript` processor to achieve this. I have provided a [template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/508b25a6075cce4c64c9012976efd403) with an example, which you can import directly into your NiFi instance and connect to your flow. The body of the `ExecuteScript` processor is provided below (you can see how I initialized the AES/GCM cipher, and change the algorithm, key, and IV to your desired values).

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.SecretKey
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

FlowFile flowFile = session.get()

if (!flowFile) {
    return
}

try {
    // Get the raw values of the attributes
    String normalAttribute = flowFile.getAttribute('Normal Attribute')
    String sensitiveAttribute = flowFile.getAttribute('Sensitive Attribute')

    // Instantiate an encryption cipher
    // Lots of additional code could go here to generate a random key, derive a key from a password, read from a file or keyring, etc.
    String keyHex = "0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210" // * 2 for 256-bit encryption
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyHex.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES")
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyHex[0..&lt;16].getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

    Cipher aesGcmEncCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding", "BC")
    aesGcmEncCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv)

    String encryptedNormalAttribute = Base64.encoder.encodeToString(aesGcmEncCipher.doFinal(normalAttribute.bytes))
    String encryptedSensitiveAttribute = Base64.encoder.encodeToString(aesGcmEncCipher.doFinal(sensitiveAttribute.bytes))

    // Add a new attribute with the encrypted normal attribute
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'Normal Attribute (encrypted)', encryptedNormalAttribute)

    // Replace the sensitive attribute inline with the cipher text
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'Sensitive Attribute', encryptedSensitiveAttribute)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("There was an error encrypting the attributes: ${e.getMessage()}")
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
```

Comment: Hey @Andy, thanks for your comment.  I am trying to do this in Python using the execute script processor, I'm using the `from Crypto.Cipher import AES` module, but it gives me an error saying no module named Crypto.  This module exists when I write the code in a python file outside of nifi.  Any idea why this is happening? Any suggested work arounds?  Here's the whole code [link](https://repl.it/EJU7/0) in case you wanted to look at it.

Comment: You'll need to tell NiFi where the Python modules are (forgive my unfamiliarity with Python nomenclature). You can do this in the processor property for "Module Directory" as described by Matt Burgess [here](http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/03/executescript-json-to-json-revisited_14.html?m=1) in his article on Jython and `ExecuteScript`.

Comment: Also, I think I misinterpreted your original question as dealing with flowfile attributes rather than JSON attributes, but it appears you moved past that and know how to use JSON parsing and encryption successfully. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's totally cool! You're post gave me an idea of how to approach the problem! You really helped me out! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Quick follow up question @Andy, it's cool if you don't know what's causing this error.  I added the module directory path `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.pyc`  however, I am still getting the error, no module named Crypto.  I tried modifying the path to end at Crypto, but it didn't solve the error.

Comment: I'll set it up on one of my deployments and comment here if I figure it out. I'll also get in touch with Matt and see if he knows.

Comment: Was able to get in touch with Matt! Apparently even though nifi says "python" it's actually jython.  So it doesn't accept python modules.

Comment: I used the template you provided but got the following error in the ExecuteScript, 

gcm cipher cannot be reused for encryption

I am using nifi 1.6

Comment: Please open a new question and provide the complete stacktrace and configuration.

Comment: Hi Andy openeded a new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521400/nifi-execute-script-encrypt-json